# Error importing phing task file but the file is present there

Tags: php, pear, phing

2.4.12 build. i have placed the phing file inside /opt/phing and added
lines to the .bashrc.

```
export PHP_COMMAND=/usr/bin/php 
export PHING_HOME=/opt/phing 
export PHP_CLASSPATH=${PHING_HOME}/classes 
export PATH=${PATH}:${PHING_HOME}/bin
```

I am able to run the basic phing script but when i am using svnExportDiffTask it is throwing error.

```
[PHP Error] include_once(phing/tasks/ext/svn/SvnExportDiffTask.php):
            failed to open stream: No such file or directory
            [line 1057 of /opt/phing/classes/phing/Phing.php]
[PHP Error] include_once(): Failed opening 'phing/tasks/ext/svn/SvnExportDiffTask.php'
            for inclusion (include_path='/opt/phing/classes:.:/home/prateek/work/bitnami/php/lib/php') 
            [line 1057 of /opt/phing/classes/phing/Phing.php]
  [foreach] Error importing phing/tasks/ext/svn/SvnExportDiffTask.php
Execution of target "getcode" failed for the following reason:
/home/prateek/work/build/build.xml:31:35:
Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.

BUILD FAILED
/home/prateek/work/build/build.xml:31:35:
Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: which is the exact full path of `SvnExportDiffTask.php`?

Comment: @cweiske

path: /opt/phing/classes/phing/tasks/ext/svn/SvnExportDiffTask.php

Comment: the error was resolved there was no SvnExportDiffTask file but SvnExportTask file was present. Name has been changed.

Now there is another error which pops in PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PEAR_ErrorStack' not found in /opt/phing/classes/phing/tasks/ext/svn/SvnBaseTask.php on line 316

Comment: please use PEAR to install phing, so that you get all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Install phing via the PEAR installer, so that you get all dependencies automatically installed. It will solve most of your problems.